# Play a sound when the player is under Y 0.5 position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code:

```
void Update() 
{
    //Restart level
    if (gameObject.transform.position.y < -0.5) 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CubePointsLvl", 0);
        StartCoroutine( Wait3Seconds() );
        //rigidbody.AddForce(0,-100000,0);
        //transform.position = new Vector3(inputSpawnX, inputSpawnY, inputSpawnZ);
    }
}

//Wait 3 second
IEnumerator Wait3Seconds()
{
    audio.PlayOneShot(DeadSound, 1.0F);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.3f);
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

I want to play a sound when the player is under Y 0.5 position and then the game to restart. But when I debug the code, the sound is looping and I know why, but I don't know how to solve it. How can I do that? And an explication? I am using C#.

Comment: Well you know why, then explain it. Then think about what you could do to mitigate it. I think you could figure out how to handle this on your own. I'll give you a hint though by rephrasing your goal: IF sound has already played, THEN don't play sound again.

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: you can do that by tracking a boolean like `bHasPlayed = true` then initialize it to false first and assign accordingly.. also create a class level public bool or a `public bool bHasPlayed { get; set;};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting a new coroutine every frame that the player is below `-0.5` rather than just doing it once the *first* time the player goes below `-0.5`.  You could use a flag to prevent the coroutine from being started again.

```
private bool alreadyDead = false;

public void Update() {
    // Only execute if we've gone below -0.5 for the first time
    if (gameObject.transform.position.y < -0.5 && 
        alreadyDead == false) 
    {
        // Set a flag indicating this has been executed
        alreadyDead = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CubePointsLvl", 0);
        StartCoroutine( Wait3Seconds() );
    }
}

public IEnumerator Wait3Seconds()
{
    audio.PlayOneShot(DeadSound, 1.0F);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.3f);
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it works! I forgot that. I know that the sound runs every grame but I forgot the boolean. Thanks! :)